# What do ".." and "..." mean in my PHP directory listing?

Tags: php

I am using this code to get the files in a directory:

```
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: .".$file."<br />";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    } 
}
```

And I am getting this list of files:

```
filename: .map.jpg
filename: .templates 
filename: .administrator
filename: .components 
filename: .LICENSE.txt 
filename: ... 
filename: .log 
filename: .htaccess 
filename: .map.png 
filename: .logs 
filename: .cli 
filename: ..
filename: .libraries
```

What do those .. and ... mean? Does it mean some subdirectories? If so, which directory do they belong too?

Comment: `.` is the current directory, `..` the parent directory. And you are adding one dot yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `..` and `...` are directory references..... you actually displaying a single `.` before the filename itself, so they're actually `.` and `..`

- `.` refers to the current folder
- `..` refers to the parent folder

If you're in a folder at the command line, and do `cd ..`, it moves you up a level in the folder tree... that's what `..` means

If you put an `is_dir($file))` test inside your loop, you can use that to show if $file is a folder or a file

Answer (score 0):

With `opendir()` you also read the current directory which is a simple dot (`.`) and the parent directory which are two dots (`..`). You also see these when you are on a server via ftp you see these to browse through the filesystem